# Помогите пожалуйста исправить ошибку в библиотеке sqlite3 в python3

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3

Пайтон код выдает ошибку:

```py
import sqlite3 as sq

db = sq.connect("something.db")
```

Пытался сделать бд на пайтон с помощью туториалов на ютубе, ничего не получилось, потом зашел в официальную документацию о sqlite3 в пайтон, но там предоставляется точно такой же код.

Пайтон (версия 3.11.3) выдает такую ошибку:

```
db = sq.connect("something.db")
     ^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'sqlite3' has no attribute 'connect' (most likely due to a circular import).
```

Как я понял пайтон не может найти функцию `connect`, но даже если так, то чем ее заменить и каким образом? Что делать? Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: а ваш файл с кодом как называется? не sqlite3.py случайно?

Comment: strawdog, спасибо, совсем забыл о такой мелкой вроде бы детали как название питон файла

Answer (score 1):

strawdog помог в комментариях, спасибо. Файл действительно был назван sqlite3.py и поэтому код не работал.